# symfony2 (doctrine) currency constraint not working

Tags: validation, symfony, annotations, doctrine, constraints

I have an entity set up like this:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
```

...

```
/**
 * @var decimal $amount
 * @Assert\Currency
 * @ORM\Column(name="amount", type="decimal")
 */
private $amount;
```

If I submit my form with blank in the amount field nothing happens. Shouldn't my form automatically throw an error or what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a NotBlank assertion (@Assert\NotBlank) to validate that that field wasn't submitted with empty data. If that passes, then your other assertions should run on any actual data submitted.

Comment: Most of Symfony's validators don't make assumptions about whether or not data should exist.  [Here's a link to the Currency validator](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Constraints/CurrencyValidator.php#L37) where you can see if the value is null or empty string it doesn't throw any errors.